# Compilation Error in C program that returns the integer with the highest occurrence in sequence of integer input

Tags: c, arrays, loops, user-input, frequency

I have a C program that reads a sequence of non-negative integers, and prints the sequence twice, with one element per line. The requirement is that the input contains no more than 1000 integers.
Instead of scanf, I'm using a module called getint() that reads an integer input and if it reads -1 or EOF, the program ends.
I'm getting several compilation errors which I think are due to the fact that my code is trying to access an index of my array that is out of the range.
Could someone help me out because I really don't get how to fix it.

```
// ar_max(a[]) returns the max entry of a

int ar_max(int a[]) {

  int max_so_far = a[0];

  for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {

    if (a[i] > max_so_far) {

      max_so_far = a[i];
    }
  }
  return max_so_far;
}


int main() {

  int inputnum = getint();

  // array containing the distinct numbers seen

  int a_num[1000] = {};

  // array containing the frequencies of the distinct numbers seen

  int a_freq[1000] = {};

  int len_n;

  while (inputnum != -1) {

    int i = 0;

    len_n = i + 1;

//int len_f = i;

// update the frequency of inputnum if it's already been seen

    for (i = 0; i < len_n; i++, len_n = i+1) {

          if (a_num[i] == inputnum) {

            a_freq[i] = a_freq[i] + 1;

          }

        }

        // add inputnum into the array if it hasn't already been seen

        if (i == len_n) {

          a_num[i+1] = inputnum;

          a_freq[i+1] = 1;

        }

        inputnum = getint();

      }

  // print the first number with the highest frequency

  for (int j = 0; j < len_n; j++) {

    if (a_freq[j] == ar_max(a_freq)) {

      printf("%d\n", a_num[j]);

      break;

    }

  }

}
```

The compilation errors are:

```
Stack buffer overflow on address 0x7fff88d20050. Check array indices.
  Error caused by read of size 4 byte(s) to 0x7fff88d20050:
  frame 0: main, freq.c:37:11
  frame 1: __libc_start_main, libc-start.c:226:0
  frame 2: _start, from module A6-getint.c-g38-binary (+0x41ba94)

  0x7fff88d20050 is contained 4064 bytes into stack frame:
  frame 0: main, freq.c:24:0

  This frame has 7 object(s):
  4 byte object inputnum located 48 bytes into frame.
  4000 byte object a_num located 64 bytes into frame.  Access overflew this variable.
  4000 byte object a_freq located 4192 bytes into frame.
  4 byte object len_n located 8320 bytes into frame.
  4 byte object i located 8336 bytes into frame.
  4 byte object j located 8352 bytes into frame.
Program finished with exit code 1 (An error occurred).
```

Comment: Please post the compilation errors

Comment: I added them at the bottom :)

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't compilation errors, those are runtime errors.

Yes, you are correct in thinking this must be an array bounds problem.  The only way for line 37 to crash is if j>1000

I see that you are not initializing len_n, and if you never enter the while loop (meaning inputnum immediately returned -1) then j may go past 1000 in that latter loop.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code is a problem:

```
for (i = 0; i < len_n; i++, len_n = i+1) {
```

the for loop will never finish (until `len_n` overflows the amount allowed in an int).

Each time round the loop, you are

1. Incrementing `i`
2. Setting `len_n` to `i+1`
3. Checking if `i` is still less than `len_n`. Of course it is less that `len_n` because you just set `len_n` to `i+1`!

Comment: I fixed that by initializing another variable to be equal to len_n and remain unchanged and replaced the len_n in i<len_n. It solved the error but now my program just returns 0 not matter what the input...?

Comment: You should try running it in a debugger. That will allow you to check the values of your variables as you step through the program. One other problem is that you are resetting `len_n` each time round the outer loop. You should just set it to 0 before the loop and increment it if you need to (i.e. when you go into the "hasn't been seen" part).

Comment: ?? len_n is set as 0 before the while loop begins

Comment: Not in the code you posted - it just says `int len_n;` that doesn't set it to 0. You do set it to `i + 1` inside the while loop, but that is neither 0 or before the while loop begins.

Comment: What if i define it as a global variable before the main function? Because even if i initialize it as 0 before the while loop, my program prints 0

Comment: No need to make it a global variable. Setting it to 0 just requires a `len_n = 0;` statement. Are you still resetting it to 1 in this line: `len_n = i + 1;`? As I said, you need to learn how to use a debugger, it really helps in these situations.